# Some pointless line when "send answers via email" is unfolded

Tags: bug, design

If I ask a question I'm offered to have answers sent to me via email. There's a corresponding link for that at the bottom of the page

[image]

note that when the link is not clicked all I have is a bar asking me "Would you like" and then there's some empty space and then comes the page bottom bar with "about", "help" and the like.

When I click the link the following unfolds:

[image]

note that there's "Save email settings" and then there's a horizontal line and then comes the empty space and the page bottom. That horizontal line is only displayed when the link is clicked.

What does that line do? Why is it only shown when the link is clicked?

It looks like it is redundant and should just be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug, it's there to separate that section when you [ask a new queston](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):

> [image]

The dev team found no reason to have different view for those two cases, feel free to start feature request asking for this, though personally I think it's too minor to matter.